# output alignment issue with lists

Tags: python, printing, output

Am trying to get an output that is left justified..but i keep getting alignment issues. here is my code:

```
def print_report(symbol:str,strategy:str, alist1:list, alist2:list, alist3:list, alist4:list):
    print('\nSYMBOL:   ', symbol.upper())
    print('STRATEGY: ', strategy)
    print('\n''DATE            CLOSING        INDICATOR        SIGNAL')
    for i in range(0,len(alist1)):
        print('{0:<0}{1:>13}{2:>15}{3:>15}'.format(alist1[i],alist2[i],alist3[i],alist4[i]))
```

The output should look like:

```
DATE          CLOSING     INDICATOR       SIGNAL
2013-10-01     887.00        0.00               
2013-10-02     887.99        0.00               
2013-10-03     876.09        0.00               
2013-10-04     872.35        0.00               
2013-10-07     865.74      877.83         SELL
2013-10-08     853.67      871.17         SELL
2013-10-09     855.86      864.74         SELL
2013-10-10     868.24      863.17          BUY
2013-10-11     871.99      863.10          BUY
2013-10-18    1011.41      911.27          BUY
2013-10-21    1003.30      936.71          BUY
```

Is there an easier way to get the output? or align them properly?

Comment: What issues? Can you show us what you are getting?

Comment: Do you mean [**right**-justified](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rjust)?

Comment: Well, use `'{0:<0}{1:>13}{2:>17}{3:>17}'.format(...)`...

Comment: the problem lies in the last part where the BUY and SELL are not aligned.

Comment: You might want to use some sort of `'{0:width}  {1:>width}  {2:>width}  {3:<width}'` formatting (note the spaces in the format string itself), then you won't have these alignment issues. :)

Comment: can i just right justify the last column with the code that I have?

Comment: I think I got it..Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print the heading with the same format as the data rows.

```
def print_report(symbol:str, strategy:str,
                 dates:list, closings:list, indicators:list, signals:list):
    fmt = '{0[0]:<0}{0[1]:>13}{0[2]:>15}{0[3]:>15}'
    print()
    print('SYMBOL:   ', symbol.upper())
    print('STRATEGY: ', strategy)
    print()
    print(fmt.format(('DATE', 'CLOSING', 'INDICATOR', 'SIGNAL')))
    for d in zip(dates, closings, indicators, signals):
        print(fmt.format(d))
```

You can use a different format for the header if you like, but the point is, use the `format` method for the header as well.

Comment: the last part BUY and SELL are still misaligned..can we make them aligned as well?